# shntool splits .wav files at the wrong split points

Tags: linux, audio, zsh, wav

I am on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, and I am using the most recent version of the Oh My ZSH shell.

I am using shntool (specifically shnsplit) from the terminal to split .wav files for albums into separate tracks by piping the results of a call to `cuebreakpoints` into a call to `shnsplit`. The tracks are being split at the wrong breakpoints. This happens for several different albums by different artists for which the files were acquired from different sources. There is no error or crashing, just incorrect output.

Specifically, the first *N-1* tracks of an *N* track album are each split to length less than one minute each, and the final track consists of the remainder of the full album file. The same `cuebreakpoints` output results in the same manifested split points each time, but the manifested split points seem to have no correspondence to those listed in the `cuebreakpoints` output.

I have checked the `cuebreakpoints` output for correctness, and matched it against the format listed in the manpages for shntool, so I am pretty sure there is nothing wrong with `cuebreakpoints`. I have been using this same piped command for years, and it only recently started manifesting this bug. The command is given below.

`cuebreakpoints album.cue | shnsplit -o flac album.wav`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems that recent (?) versions of `shnsplit` don't like the cue `mm:ss:ff` format - instead, they need `mm:ss:fff`. The problem is that `cuebreakpoints` outputs `mm:ss:ff` (at least in some cases).

Here's what I did to fix:

1. Change the command `cuebreakpoints album.cue | shnsplit -o flac album.wav` to `shnsplit -f album.cue -o "flac flac -s -o %f -" album.wav`
2. Manually fix the cue sheet so that all `INDEX` entries have a time format of `mm:ss:fff` ([as found here](https://hydrogenaud.io/index.php/topic,112637.msg933565.html#msg933565))

Answer (score 0):

At least version 3.0.10 of shnsplit doe not handle 24bit audio correctly and completely messes up on it. It is a bug.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1138591)